# selected value from bootstrap selectpicker not showing up in form

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, select

I have a form that inserts a record to a db, it uses GetSQLValueString($_GET['selectName'], "text") to gather values from the form. Using bootstrap's form-control class allows the value to appear in the sent query string of values, when I add the selectpicker class it no longer shows a value in the query string as if the select didn't exist.

It has a proper name and id attribute. The Bootstrap Select pulg-in seems to work properly as far as styling my select. When I substitute an input field with the same name the value shows in the query string. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong

Comment: I encounter the same issue, did you manage to work around ?